# Why doesn't the color change?

Tags: dart, flutter

Want to change the color of a `RaisedButton`. It doesn't work, and I also don't get any errors.

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: null,
  color: Colors.red,
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tirth is right, but in case you want to keep the button disabled, you can change the color of the button like this

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: null,
  disabledColor: Colors.red,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you've set `onPressed` to `null`, button gets disabled. Set a method call or anonymous function there.

```
RaisedButton(
  color: Colors.red,
  onPressed: () => print("Press");
);
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote & accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: @TirthPatel The answer is correct (+1) to some extent but not when button is supposed to be disabled.